# Virtual keyboard with auto show feature

Tags: keyboard, accessibility

I want a virtual keyboard that opens up automaticly when editing a textbox or similar. (Just like on the phone) and closes again when something outside of a textbox is in focus.

First I found that 'onboard' has this feature so I installed it and tried to set it up. The keyboard looks nice but the 'open when editing text' feature doesn't work for me. The keyboard doesn't show up if I am editing text in the browser/console/text document etc.

So I am asking if 'onboard' just don't work on raspbian or if I should use a different virtual keyboard.

---

Running on raspbian buster. I can change to a different version if needed.